# Bootstrap 4 carousel on mobile browser

Tags: jquery, angular, jquery-mobile, bootstrap-4, carousel

i recently developed a site that uses **Bootstrap 4(4.4.1)** and **Angular 7** and **carousel**. Now on desktop everything works properly, clicking left / right arrows navigates properly, BUT when i load the site on mobile device, ***Swiping*** the carousel does nothing. If i use the arrows all is great, but when it comes to swipe, nothing happens **until i use the *Right* arrow**. After the initial scroll through the right button, the swipe works like a charm. So my question here is what should i do in order for the carousel to swipe with no problems without clicking the right arrow first.

Here is the HTML code for the carousel

```
<div id="dataCR" class="carousel slide full-width"
    data-interval="false"
    data-wrap="false"
    data-touch="true"
    data-keyboard="false"
    data-pause="true"
    data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner full-height">
        <div class="carousel-item" [ngClass]="{'active': i===0}" *ngFor="let item of data; let i = index; let first = first;">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"
                    *ngFor="let obj of item; let j = index; let firstA = first;" >
                    <app-card
                          [card]="obj"
                          [isIndicator]="obj.isIndicator">
                    </app-card>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev leftRs"
        href="#dataCR"
        data-slide="prev"
        (click)="handleCarouselClick($event, 'prev')"
        *ngIf="data.length > 1 && this.currentPage > 0">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next rightRs"
        href="#dataCR"
        data-slide="next"
        (click)="handleCarouselClick($event, 'next')"
        *ngIf="data.length > 1 && this.currentPage < (data.length - 1)">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
    </a>
</div>
```

I also tried to use JQuery but it was not successful. I tried to capture the slide events and even to add slide events but literally nothing happens.

Here is the code i use for that:

```
$('#dataCR').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {
    console.log('here we are');
});

$(document).ready(function() {
     // THESE 2 ARE CRUSHING WITH .swiperight is not a function
     (<any>$('#dataCR')).swiperight(function() {
         console.log('here we are - PREV');
     });
     (<any>$('#dataCR')).swipeleft(function() {
         console.log('here we are - NEXT');
     });


     // THESE 2 ARE COMPILING BUT IT'S LIKE THEY ARE NEVER BEING CALLED
     $(document).on('swipeleft', '.carousel', function (e) {
              console.log("swipe left");
     });
     $(document).on('swiperight', '.carousel', function (e) {
              console.log("swipe right");
     });
});
```

Any help on the matter will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the thing that fixed my issue is the following one :

1. in angular.json fine integrate the jQuery and Bootstrap scripts in this order.
2. in the component where you are defining the carousel right after

```
import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectorRef, HostListener, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
```

add this line

```
declare var $:any;
```

and then in ngOnInit add the following code:

```
let self = this;
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#dataCR').carousel({
         interval: false
     });
     $('#dataCR').on('slid.bs.carousel', function ($event) {
         // This event handles the completed slide animation.
         // here you can find the direction of the animation and 
         // from which to which slide it went.
         // Its useful if you want to track paging etc.
     });
});
```

After these steps the swipe works as expected on mobile devices